# How to redirect all example.org traffic to example.com from ONLY 1 country?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have two sites, example.com and example.org and I want to redirect all the people visiting from a Country X visiting example.org to example.com, how to do it using php or .htaccess ?

in short, both sites will work but for a Country X ip's, the visitors browsing .org will redirect to .com without them knowing

Comment: What do you think, how could it be solved?

Comment: how are you planning to determine where your visitor is comming from? you'd have to resolve his ip and look where his provider is located at. i think there are some commercial ip resolving services for that exact purpose.

Comment: and i don't think that redirection "without them knowing" is possible at all. if you redirect in php via header("Location :.....") your user will see that the host changed in his browser. if you do a redirect via mod_rewrite in .htaccess he most likely will see it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GEO IP lookup tool, like 
http://www.hostip.info/use.html

You can use their service in php - your index.php would like something like this:

```
$r = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.1");
```

Alternatively, a much faster method is to purchase the ip database list from max mind (it's $50). http://www.maxmind.com/app/country
Then you simply query that database (after loading it into mysql) and bump them based on country.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done with .htaccess.... as far as I know.

You'd need to use php to do some geoip location, detect the counrty and then do a simple php header("Location") change with a 301 redirection.

This is a good free database: http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php

You'll just need to import it into a database and query it with php.